# how to dismiss a popover and show an activity indicator while doing more processing

Tags: ios, popover, uiactivityindicatorview

Converting an application to work on iPad.  Need some help in understanding the sequence of processing popovers, dismissals and activity indicators.

Here is the desired sequence:

1. Present a tableview wrapped in a navigation controller inside a popover.
2. Select a row from the table.
3. Send info from that row to the primary view controller (parent).
4. Dismiss the popover completely.
5. Show an activity indicator showing that processing is occurring.
6. Do some processing.
7. Make the activity indicator disappear.
8. Draw the graphics on the primary view.

I have been able to do all the above except the popover stays on the screen until all the processing is done and the graphics drawn.  The activity indicator shows up momentarily when the popover disappears.  I have tried delegates, notifications and setters, to no avail.  It appears that all the processes inside a method don't necessarily execute in sequence and the popover view holds on until everything is executed (in this case the select row method).

Where do I put both the processing code and the activity indicators so everything works in the right order?

Comment: Put some code. Then we can help.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.  I will work through some of the suggestions and then post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very straight forward implementation

Check the following list

1. Create a delegate of the viewController shown in popover
2. Set the delegate of popover viewController as main viewController
3. Keep a reference of popover in main viewController to dismiss it once event is received.
4. Once event is received dismiss the popover after getting the selected value
5. Show an activity indicator view or HUD
6. Dismiss the activity indicator once processing is done

[Source code](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/TestPopover.zip) for a demo app doing this.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your source code was very helpful.  Helped me to understand the delegate process more clearly.  On running, the source failed, says it is missing a -lpod file, but the real issue is where do I put the processing code.  When I put it anywhere in the selectedRowAtIndexPath method (where dismiss, getting data and activating indicator are) in the view controller, the popover is not dismissed until after the processing is complete.

Comment: @mikemiller I have added an HUD `SVProgressHUD` through `Cocoapods` you need to run the project from `*.workspace` instead of `*.xcodeproj`. The processing code should be in the main viewController. Before starting the processing dismiss the popover, show the hud etc. Step through the source code for the work flow.

Comment: Code runs just fine.  Did experiment with adding a loop (int a;for (int t=0; t<1000000000; t++) {a=t;) after last line in selectedRowAtIndexPath.  The popover only dismisses after the loop is finished. So the processing code can't go there. I can't seem to trace where things go from there.

Comment: Here is the complete method:-                   (void)viewController:(SecondViewController *)viewController selectedRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{[_popoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    _selectedRow = _rows[indexPath.row];
    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Please wait"
                         maskType:SVProgressHUDMaskTypeGradient];
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0f target:self selector:@selector(dismissHUD) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    int a;for (int t=0; t<1000000000; t++) {a=t;}
}

Comment: @mikemiller Try to use dispatch_aync to run long running processes. Replace the for loop with this `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        int a;for (int t=0; t<1000000000; t++)
        {a=t;}
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Make the `UIPopoverController` instance a iVar. Alloc Init it with your required view controller on some button method or whatever you have designed. Make a protocol from your popover controller's root view controller and make the parent view controller conform to it. On the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method, call that delegate to popover's parent view controller. On the message reception in parent view controller, dismiss the popover controller instance and do your processing there. (Do Manage the memory well if the project does not support ARC because the popover might be alloc inited several times.)

Comment: When I dismiss the popover and then begin processing in the same method (message in this case), the popover does not dismiss until all the processing is completed. Does the method have to be completed before it is dismissed?  It does not seem to be linear in its processing.